# Teamcity - manually restart a test through web interface

Tags: teamcity

In a project with multiple sub components(workflows), I was hoping to just restart a single workflow. Previously in Github actions you could just click into the failed test and there was a button to just click restart workflow, is there something similar in Teamcity, if it exists a screenshot of this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
In the end the solution was because I was part of an organisation, and at the time not given the correct permissions in Teamcity, so the blue run button on the top right was not showing. Once permissions were fixed it became easy to re run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually re-run a job.  Like this [Experimental UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTcrz.png) or like this [Classic UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Numov.png).

If you want to have a job retry on failure, then you can add a [Retry Trigger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-retry-build-trigger.html)